# Sitecore queries in Experience Editor

Tags: sitecore

I've read that fast queries always execute against the database so I'm using regular sitecore queries. I'm running into a performance snag only in the experience editor and I wonder if the queries do not hit the cache in Experience Editor.

Do the regular sitecore queries ever get cached in Experience Editor?

UPDATE 1:
Just to elaborate on the issue. I have 100+ renderings on an item and I've been able to get past the performance issues on the published website by using html caching. But when I load that item in XE it takes a couple minutes to load. I want to start the tuning by ensure that the queries executed by some of the sublayouts are hitting the cache.

Comment: Post up details of the query you are running and some sample code, and more details of exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: What do you mean with "regular sitecore queries" XPath? XPath is horrible slow, compared with fast query or the search api. (Lucine / Solr)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question; there is SOME level of caching involved. Your DataProvider will cache the items resolved by your query and so on. But your query as a whole, will not get cached.

That said; Sitecore Query (and fast:/ variants of same) really have no business being in any code that executes run-time. These are meant for Content Editor pre-selection of fields, treelists and so on.

Your HTML caching might save you now, but be careful if you are indeed using Sublayouts - some of your code might still be executing, HTML cache or not.

Sooner or later you will find that your solution, overall, is underperforming - again regardless of HTML caching. Set up Sitecore ContentSearch and rewrite your queries is the better long term solution.